# Picker value popup open twice

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms.Picker to show country list. It works properly in normal scenario. I have kept the one (downarrow.png) image, if user click on the image then I run below code to open select picker value. The problem is that it works but show picker value selection popup twice if user click on image. This problem occurred only in Android platform.

picker.focus()

Additional Information :

Xamarin.Forms version : 3.4.0.1008975

Comment: Could you upgrade to Xamarin.Forms 3.6? It seems my fix is included there: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4909

Comment: facing same issue.!

Comment: Thank you to update but we can't upgrade our Xamarin.Forms DLL for some time because of some other dependencies. Although, It fixed by this code in Android picker renderer. Control.Focusable = false;      Control.FocusableInTouchMode = false;

Comment: @JohnSmith but by applying this in renderer, it will work like, picker will get focused only when click on down arrow, and it will not get focused on tapping it?

Comment: @JohnSmith I seem to have found a workaround. Simply just call Unfocus right after your Focus.

Comment: @John Smith, I can not reproduce your issue at my side, but you can try to call Unfocus right after your Focus